# Docker cant´t find, pull images : server mis behaving

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-registry, docker-image, docker-run

Docker toolbox installed for windows 10 Home Edition. Docker toolbox for this OS is installed. But when I can start learning the program, it gives me these errors. I cannot create an image or run an image. At the end of each error message it tells me that I have a server misbehaving. At the moment of running an image gives me the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest'
locally
latest: Pulling from library / busybox
d9cbbca60e5f: Pulling fs layer C: \Program Files\ Docker Toolbox\ docker.exe: error pulling image configuration: Get https: //registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/busybox/blobs/sha256:78096d0a54788961ca68393e5f8038704b97d8af374249dc5c8faec1b8045e42: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving.
  See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

And at the momento to pulling and image, i got this:

```
$ docker pull busybox
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
d9cbbca60e5f: Pulling fs layer                                                                                          error pulling image configuration: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/busybox/blobs/sha256:78096d0a54788961ca68393e5f8038704b97d8af374249dc5c8faec1b8045e42: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: server misbehaving
```

This is my docker info :

```
$ docker info                                                                                           Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc version: 3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.14.154-boot2docker
 Operating System: Boot2Docker 19.03.5 (TCL 10.1)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 989.5MiB
 Name: default
 ID: ANYM:Q52D:BUAW:R6IO:HTFN:S4I6:JLX6:WVNK:QEGO:OHCZ:PCHP:NWJN
 Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: dsabillon94
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
  provider=virtualbox
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

Docker version

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.7
 Git commit:        74b1e89e8a
 Built:             Wed Jul 31 15:18:18 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea838
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:28:45 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these options

1. Wipe everything and re-install
2. Switch to Beta version.
3. You can also set DNS Server to 8.8.8.8 and try again pulling an image.

I hope one of option will help you :)